# How to make network graph of twitter (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, twitter, networkx

I'm beginner programing who try to analyze network of my twitter account.
I am writing this code:

```
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key = my_consumer_key,
          consumer_secret = my_consumer_secret, 
          access_token_key = my_access_token_key, 
          access_token_secret = my_access_token_secret, 
          input_encoding = "UTF-8",
          sleep_on_rate_limit=True)


friends = api.GetFriends()

G = networkx.Graph()

for friend in friends:
   G.add_edge(myname,friend.screen_name)


for friend in friends[-3:]:
    for user in api.GetFriends(friend.id):
        if user in friends:
            G.add_edge(friend.screen_name,user.screen_name)


pos = spring_layout(G)


draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size = 100, node_color = 'w')
draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width = 1)
draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size = 12, font_family = 'sans-
serif', font_color = 'r')

xticks([])
yticks([])
savefig("egonetwork.png") 
show()
```

I could get result however it was so complicated because of huge amount of nodes. Therefore I want to pick up less the number of nodes(followers) for example, 5 or 6 nodes only. Which part should I edit ?
It would be appreciated if it is explained in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to choose a maximum of 5/6 followers and their interconnections.

If that is the case, I suggest you change your for loop such that at most five nodes are added to the graph. Further, you need to make sure that you only add the followers of the five followers you add to the graph.

```
for i in range(min(5, len(friends))): 
   G.add_edge(myname,friends[i].screen_name)
   for user in api.GetFriends(friends[i].id):
        if user in friends[:min(5, len(friends))]:
            G.add_edge(friend.screen_name,user.screen_name)
```

In the first for loop you will add at most five of your followers to the graph. 
The second loop will then go through all the followers of the node you just added and add it's interconnections to your other four followers.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. When I run this code, I got "int' object is not iterable" for this part "for i in min(5, len(friends)):"  and try to solve. But I couldn't make it. What is happening ?

Comment: Hey, sorry i forgot to add range(min(5, len(friends)) in the first line. Updated the answer I hope it works as intended now.